# is it possible to run selenium tests inside webview?

Tags: android, selenium, webview, android-webview

I want to run tests on my application. I know I can use selenium with chrome driver on my ubuntu machine.

I wanted to know is it possible to do the same but on a webview in an android app? I mean in building an app, import selenium and tell it to use webview that is created in that app.

So when the app starts the tests are run and finished.

Is it possible? I have no experience building android apps.
Is it possible with react native?

Answer (score 1):

Use http://appium.io/

It is capable of running on multiple devices (Real/Virtual). It can be easily setup on Ubuntu.

Hope this helps.